# In a group of people rolling dice, what is the probability that you tie for highest roll multiple times in a row?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, conditional-probability, dice

This problem was inspired by a Reddit post which you can find [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/classicwow/comments/gn4ma1/rolled_the_same_number_3_times_times_in_a_row_for/).

> You are in a group of 40 people. Each of you rolls a 100-sided die. If a single person has the highest roll, then that person wins. But if two or more people tie for the highest roll, then those people — and only those people — roll again. This process repeats until one person wins (i.e., rolls a number greater than all other numbers rolled in that round).
>
> What is the probability that you participate in three rounds of ties before someone ultimately wins on the fourth round?

Can you generalize this to a group of $P$ people, a die with $Q$ sides, and $R$ rounds of ties?

Comment: When you say "What is the probability that *you*..." do you mean a *particular* person chosen ahead of time, or instead (really) *one*, that there is *someone* who participates in three rounds of ties?

Comment: I intended it to mean one particular person.

Answer (score 0):

I'll outline a method that *will* solve the problem, but won't bother doing whatever simplifications that exist.

First off, completely split every round separately. In one round, what you have is a group of $P$ people rolling $Q$ sided dice. You now have a distribution over how many people tie for rolling the highest number, say $1\leq P'\leq P$ (and whether you are in it or not).

In the next round, you have the same problem: $P'$ people are rolling $Q$ sided dice.

Essentially, you have a Markov chain, which is a transition matrix $T$, with $$T_{ij}=\Pr(\text{Round }n+1\text{ has }j\text{ people remaining}\mid\text{Round }n\text{ has }i\text{ people remaining})\text{.}$$
If $\vec{v}$, a row vector, is the distribution of remaining people at round $n$ (for any $n$, including $0$), then $\vec{v}T$ is the distribution at the next round.

At round $0$, there are exactly $P$ people, so $\vec{v}=[0,\dotsc,1]$ (of length $P$). You want to look at the distribution at round $R+1$, and pick off the probability of a unique winner, which is simply $\vec{v}T^{R+1}[1,\dotsc,0]^T$.

It remains to specify $T$. These entries can be computed as follows:

1. Fix $i$, the current players first, then there are going to be $Q^i$ equally likely outcomes.
2. The number of ways, hence probability to get (i) highest number exactly $k$, (ii) with exactly $j\leq i$ people rolling it is simply $$\binom{i}{j}\left(\frac{1}{Q}\right)^j\left(\frac{k-1}{Q}\right)^{i-j}\text{.}$$
3. We don't care about $k$, so simply sum this thing right up:
   $$T_{ij}=\frac{1}{Q^i}\binom{i}{j}\sum_{k=1}^{Q-1}k^{i-j}\text{.}$$
   This sum of powers of integers [has been studied extensively, but there's no "simple" formula](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/sums-of-powers-of-positive-integers-introduction).
4. In your version of the problem, you additionally have to consider that **you** are in the set of people who have rolled the highest. If there are $j$ people rolling the highest, your chance of being one of them is...
   $$T_{ij}=\frac{j}{i}\frac{1}{Q^i}\binom{i}{j}\sum_{k=1}^{Q-1}k^{i-j}$$
   Note that the probabilities don't sum to $1$ any more, but that's not a problem - the missing probability mass is "you lost the game".

As a framing challenge, I suggest that focusing on one specified person is not important: *anyone* could have seen this event and posted about it, so the $p$-value in statistical terms should not count that.